How to use JSCH on Android with Keystore
I want to create a simple SSH client on android, but I've run into a problem: I can't use JSCH with Keystore, so far I've created two classes in my project KeysManager that generate the Keypair, and can retrieve the Public Key.
package ssh.code.editor

import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties
import java.security.KeyPair
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator
import java.security.KeyStore

class KeysManager {
    var error = ""

    fun generateKeyPair(name:String, size:Int): KeyPair? {
        try{
            val parameter = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(name, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY).apply {
                setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                setKeySize(size)
            }.build()
            return KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore").apply { initialize(parameter) }.generateKeyPair()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            error=""
            error+=e.message
            return null
        }
    }

    fun getPublicKey(name:String):String{
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
            load(null)
        }
        val entry = keyStore.getEntry(name, null)
        if(entry !is KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry){
            error="Key is not present"
            return ""
        }
        return String(entry.certificate.publicKey.encoded)
    }
}

and SSH that handle the basic operation that are needed
package ssh.code.editor

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.Vector

class SSH(host: String, user: String, private var key: String, var privateKey:String, port: Int = 22) {
    //ERROR variable
    var error:String=""

    //JSCH variables
    private var jsch = JSch()
    private var session:Session?=try {
        jsch.getSession(host, user, port)
    }
    catch(e:JSchException){
        error+=e.message
        null
    }?.
    apply {
        //How to set keys?
        connect()
    }

    private var execChannel : ChannelExec = session?.openChannel("exec") as ChannelExec
    private var sftpChannel : ChannelSftp = session?.openChannel("sftp") as ChannelSftp

    private fun inputStreamToString(inputStream: InputStream):String{
        val byteOut = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        while (inputStream.read(buffer)!=-1){
            byteOut.write(buffer, 0, 1024)
        }
        return byteOut.toString("UTF-8")
    }

    fun runCommand(command: String):String{
        if(execChannel.isClosed) return ""
        execChannel.setCommand(command)
        execChannel.connect()
        val s =  inputStreamToString(execChannel.inputStream)
        execChannel.disconnect()
        return s
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun itemInDirectory(path: String):Array<String>{
        var result= emptyArray<String>()
        for (entry:LsEntry in sftpChannel.ls(path) as Vector<LsEntry>){
            result+=entry.filename
        }
        return result
    }

    fun getFile(serverPath:String) = inputStreamToString(sftpChannel.get(serverPath))

    fun loadFile(serverPath:String, data:String) = sftpChannel.put(data.byteInputStream(), serverPath)
}

I've read on the developer android site that the private key can't be retrieved and the message has to be sent throught the API to be decrypted.
So is there a way to use JSCH with Keystore, or there is another SSH API that I can use instead of JSCH
I tried searching on the internet for an answer but i didn't find anything
So I am asking for help please
